Next auth v5 not taking up the base path
I recently upgraded from next auth v4 to v5 [5.0.0 beta.18] . I have a base path ['/ui/abc'] set in next.config.js file. I'm using azure ad provider and upon calling signin,the route is not picking up the base path of my application. How can I set the base path for v5 auth?.After the removal of basePath from next.config.js file, authentication works as expected.
I tried setting the basePath inside the auth.ts file below the providers array and removed the NEXTAUTH_URL form .env file as given in docs

There's an open pull request summarising the issue here:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/10797

More discussions here:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/9274

From the first link with the pull request, two current workarounds are:

Installing the test package by @k3k8 with their instructions (source):

... you can test my code using the following method:
git clone -b fix-base-path https://github.com/k3k8/next-auth.git
cd next-auth
corepack enable pnpm
pnpm install
pnpm build
cd packages/next-auth/
pnpm pack

This will generate a package file named something like next-auth-5.0.0-beta.20.tgz.
Move this file to your project directory and install it by updating your package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next-auth": "./next-auth-5.0.0-beta.20.tgz"
  }
}

Then run pnpm install to update your dependencies.


Use @ThangHuuVu's workaround  (source):

...my workaround is basically appending the base path like this:
// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "auth";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

const reqWithBasePath = (req: NextRequest, basePath = "/authjs") => {
  const baseUrl = new URL(
    (req.headers.get("x-forwarded-proto") ?? "https") +
      "://" +
      (req.headers.get("x-forwarded-host") ?? req.nextUrl.host)
  );
  const urlWithBasePath = new URL(
    `${basePath}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`,
    baseUrl
  );
  return new NextRequest(urlWithBasePath.toString(), req);
};

export const GET = (req: NextRequest) => {
  const nextReq = reqWithBasePath(req);
  return handlers.GET(nextReq);
};

export const POST = (req: NextRequest) => {
  const nextReq = reqWithBasePath(req);
  return handlers.POST(nextReq);
};

https://github.com/ThangHuuVu/next-auth-behind-proxy/blob/cde4368b46fbda57157d62eaf1b93b258f5fadde/app/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D/route.ts


There is a third workaround by andreynovikov here:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/121



